# Tooltip with a triangle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAutM/4/) for this question.

```css
a.tip {
    position: relative;
}

a.tip span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 60px;
    width: 125px;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* this works only in camino/firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* this is just for Safari */
}

a:hover.tip {
    font-size: 99%; /* this is just for IE */
}

a:hover.tip span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<center><a href="http://google.com/" class="tip">Link!<span>Hi its me!</span></a></center>
```

Basically I have a tooltip on my site, and it appears to the right of my link. But on the left hand side of the black box I would like a triangle attached to the box pointing to the link, is it possible to do this using only CSS? just like this but to the left

[image: tooltip with arrow]

Comment: Did you try putting a background image on the tooltip?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can do it with CSS, by using the [css triangle trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

```
a.tip span:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;

    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right:8px solid black;
    left:-8px;

    top:7px;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/dAutM/7/

---

live snippet

```css
a.tip {
  position: relative;
}

a.tip span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 60px;
  width: 125px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* this works only in camino/firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* this is just for Safari */
}

a.tip span:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid black;
  left: -8px;
  top: 7px;
}

a:hover.tip {
  font-size: 99%;
  /* this is just for IE */
}

a:hover.tip span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<center><a href="http://google.com/" class="tip">Link!<span>Hi its me!</span></a></center>
```

Comment: If you need a shadow from the triangle, you should use `filter: drop-shadow()`. `Box-shadow: ()` will not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297510/how-to-give-shadow-to-a-pointer-of-tooltip-in-html

Answer (score 25):

I developed [CSStooltip.com](http://csstooltip.com) to make tooltips with triangle in CSS only.

Example :

[image]

```
span.tooltip:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-width: 10px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: transparent #FFFFFF transparent transparent;
      top: 11px;
      left: -24px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i used the one above but this is still a great tool!

Comment: Is there anyway to be able to put a 1px border around the arrow and the tip

Answer (score 5):

Try this: http://ecoconsulting.co.uk/examples/css-tooltip/

It explains the problems and fixes the issues, and allows for an arrow and tooltip with a border.

**Contents of the link**

### CSS-only tooltips using `:after` and `:before`

These tooltip rollovers use a custom HTML5 a tag data- attribute (data-tooltip) to populate a tooltip displaying text contained in the attribute. The arrow triangle is formed by two generated overlapping elements with only the top border visible (r-l are transparent, bottom is 0px). All tooltip text is an extension of the link and therefore clickable.

View source to get code - it's as clean as possible, and each tooltip has a separate block of css styles—use the Arrow tooltip (final) CSS for the finished styles. Don't like the colour? You know what to do. Original inspiration: [Nicolas Gallagher's Pure CSS speech bubbles](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/), and a desire to emulate Addy Osmani's JQuery tooltip in pure CSS.

1. CSS-only tooltip using `:before` (no arrow)

   > This link with a CSS-styled rollover tooltip uses a `data-` attribute for the tooltip content. You can also use `:after` to generate the tooltip. A box-shadow makes it appear to float above the content.
2. CSS-only tooltip arrow with `:before` and `:after` (`a` tag inside span)

   > Since the link's :before property is already used for the tooltip text, we need an extra element to provide further generated content. This CSS-styled rollover tooltip link adds an arrow made from overlapping :before and :after properties on a span that wraps the link. The triangle has no width or height and is constructed from borders only, which means we can't use a box-shadow with positive values, as it appears outside the transparent rectangle of the l-r borders and not around the 'arrow'.

Fault: lingering triangle when hovering over arrow's 'border'.
Fault: Mozilla (Firefox): arrow border is beneath link, needs higher z-index.

3. Final CSS-only tooltip arrow with `:before` and `:after` (`span` inside `a` tag)

   > This translucent CSS-styled rollover tooltip uses a span inside the a tag. The shadow is reinstated but with negative top/left values to avoid the arrow. For a final touch alpha transparency (rgba) is applied to the tooltip elements, with trial-and-error tweaks to blend the arrow's colour into the lower gradient and reduce the visibility of the (darker) border colour of the outer triangle beneath the inner.

You can add it to any link by applying the tooltip class and wrapping the link text in a span. The tooltip inherits the span's `font-weight` value by default.

Sadly, CSS3 (in this case fade-in-nicely) transitions on generated elements aren't supported widely enough yet (FF only but even there, I couldn't get it to work).