# How to give shadow to a pointer of Tooltip> In HTML

Tags: html, css

[image]

I know I can absolute position the pointer of the Tooltip but how can I add the blur effect to the pointer? Because if I put blur effect to it, the blur will not only be shown on the bottom triangle of pointer, but also on the upper half of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try `drop-shadow` [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) css effect.

```css
.pointer {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px #b2b2b2);
  background: #fff;
}

.pointer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="pointer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis interdum cursus.</div>
```

Check filter [cross browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter%20effects)

---

Also you can achieve this by using `box-shadow` and `z-index` css property. In this you will need to make an extra block to cover the upper part of shadow using `:before/:after`.

```css
.pointer {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #b2b2b2;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pointer:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #b2b2b2;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -2;
}

.pointer:before {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pointer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis interdum cursus.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        } 
        .example {
            background: rgba(219,224,223,0.5);
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            width: auto;
        }
        .example-with-box-shadow {
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 2px 10px;
        }
        .example-with-arrow, .example-with-box-shadow, .example-with-drop-shadow {
            background: white;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .example-with-arrow::after, .example-with-box-shadow::after, .example-with-drop-shadow::after {
            border: 10px solid;
            border-top-color: currentcolor;
            border-right-color: currentcolor;
            border-bottom-color: currentcolor;
            border-left-color: currentcolor;
            border-color: white transparent transparent;
            content: "";
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -10px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="example">
        <div class="example-with-box-shadow">Tooltip with box-shadow</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #888;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #bada55;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.triangle::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    bottom: -2em;
    left: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    border: 1em solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent #bada55 #bada55;
    
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle">This is a CSS3 triangle with a proper box-shadow!</div>
```

Comment: Please could you include an explanation of why this answers the question?